# trying to append multiple images but got only one from array in angular

Tags: angular, mean

I am trying to select multiple images, and the images are being selected and stored in the state, but only one image is displayed Below is the code for the same

```
**my model in angular**

export class Product {
    public id: string;
    public name: string;        
    public imagePath: string;    

    constructor(id: string, name: string, img: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;       
        this.imagePath = img;        
    }
}


**My component.html**


<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-12">
            <button mat-stroked-button type="button" (click)="productImgPicker.click()">Pick Image</button>
            <input type="file" multiple #productImgPicker (change)="onImagePickes($event)">
        </div>
        <div class="image-preview" *ngIf="urls && newProductForm.get('image').valid" class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-12">
            <img *ngFor="let url of urls" [src]="url" [alt]="newProductForm.value.productName">
        </div>


**my component.ts**


onImagePickes(event: Event) {
    const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
    if(files) {      
      for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {        
        this.newProductForm.patchValue({image: files[i]});
        this.newProductForm.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {          
          this.urls.push(event.target.result);          
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
      }
    }    
  }  

onSaveProduct() {
    if(this.newProductForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.onImagePickes.length);
    if(this.mode === 'create') {
      this.productService.addProduct(
        this.newProductForm.value.productName,                
        this.newProductForm.value.image,
        this.newProductForm.value
          );
        } else {
          this.productService.updateProduct(
          this.productId,
          this.newProductForm.value.productName,
          this.newProductForm.value.image          
          );
        }
        this.newProductForm.reset();    
  }


**my service.ts**


addProduct(
        name: string,        
        image: File        
        ) {
        const productData = new FormData();         
        productData.append("name", name);              
        productData.append("image", image);        
        this.http
        .post<{message: string, prodId: string, prodImg: any, products: string}>('http://localhost:3000/admin/add/product', productData)
        .subscribe((resProductData) => {
          console.log(resProductData);
          const product: Product = {
            id: resProductData.prodId,
            name: name,
            imagePath: resProductData.prodImg            
          };         
          this.products.push(product);
          this.productUpdated.next([...this.products]);
        });
      }
```

backend code is working fine with multer I have checked using postman.. if anyone could help, it would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.